# Kubuntu login screen is frozen when switching users

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, login, kde, plasma

I have two users sessions running. I can switch between users without error most of the time. But after a while, after I try to switch users, on the login screen for the user I am swtiching to, the login screen is frozen solid.

The cursor works on the frozen login screen, but nothing else works. I can not login even if I try to do with without the UI reflecting my typing.

If I hit ctrl+alt+F1, I can switch back and login in to the other user, but if I try to switch to the frozen user, nothing happens.

I am using a Radeon rx580 video card...

Operating System: Kubuntu 20.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.18.5
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.68.0
Qt Version: 5.12.8
Kernel Version: 5.11.0-27-generic

Is there, at the very least, a work around to restart or kill that user session without restarting?

Comment: i faced the same issue today morning probably a bug try reporting it with log output to kde support

Comment: what are `dmesg` /`journalctl` saying? if you need to, dig into the logs.

Comment: Did you get into the TTY? Check the edit to my answer.

Comment: How much free space do you have? KDE will do this when your hard-drive gets near full. If so, consider it a blessing. : )

Comment: @NateT I have 67gb free of 227gb.

Comment: Did you have a chance of testing any of what was suggested?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there at the very least, a work around to restart or kill that user session without restarting?

from a TTY, try running the following:

```
killall kwin
startkde
```

This should hopefully restart your user session.

As for the actual fix, we will need to see logs in order to provide this. Most Daemons run on a per-session basis, so it could be literally anything freezing up a session.

**EDIT 1**

To enter TTY, you just push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> (for example) to go to TTY5. Replacing <kbd>F5</kbd> with <kbd>F6</kbd> will take you to TTY6 and so on.

You will be prompted for username and password. Once you are logged in, you should be able to run the commands in both my answer (above) and @SanchoS.ReinstateMonicaCellio 's answer. Hopefully, these will provide you with a workaround.

Next, try running the command

```
dmesg --facility=daemon
```

exactly as it is typed here. Just `dmesg` will work, but this will trim the output to what we likely need. If not, we can circle back and 'widen the net' a bit.

The result will look like a log file. The solution to your issue is likely within those logs. They are in order by date / time (listed for each log), so it should be relatively easy to find the time of the last crash and examine the logs for that time period.

If you need any extra explanation, just let us know. We are happy to explain.

Be sure to post the output of the logs to your question (during the timeframe of the last incident.)

Comment: What is a TTY? Where do I get the logs?

Comment: Enter tty with [ctrl] + [alt] + [F3].or [F4] up to [F9] I believe. It is an alternate command prompt environment that is handy for situations like yours. logs are in `/var/log`, but the commands listed in my first comment should display the ones you need.

Comment: @Scorb Did that help you to get it straightened out?

Answer (score 1):

Options to try, assuming `user2` is the user for which the session should be restarted

1. From a terminal (you can access it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>) logged into `user2`, `DISPLAY=:<d> kwin --replace`
2. From a terminal logged into `user2`, `killall -3 kwin && DISPLAY=:<d> kwin`
3. From a terminal logged into `user2`, `kquitapp5 plasmashell && kstart5 plasmashell`
4. From a terminal logged into `user2`, `killall -3 -u user2` (more radical)
5. From a terminal logged into `user1` (has to be sudoer), `sudo killall -3 -u user2` (also radical)

**Notes**:

1. To find the display number `<d>` use command `who`.
2. The core dump *might* be useful (compare the various signals, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042201/how-does-sigint-relate-to-the-other-termination-signals-such-as-sigterm-sigquit and https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html).
3. You might expect that this gets solved on its own after the next kernel/kwin update.
4. If none of the above works, perhaps slight variations/combinations do.
5. Please post the output of

   ```
   $ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
   $ echo $XDG_SESSION_ID
   $ who
   $ ps -efl | grep user2
   ```
6. Comparing the output for the cases when `user2` is not logged into a kwin session, when it is logged in, and when the session is frozen, is also instructive.

Answer (score 0):

Option 3 in the answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1360848/1418851 worked for me in a very similar case.
Perhaps this is a comment but i cannot do that because of the reputation, it may be useful for others to know.